# Maximum amount of RAM supported on a HP elitebook 840 G4

Tags: memory

i would like to know whats the maximum RAM Space for this Elitebook with this specificationS. Can it carry up to 64 GB?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, it only can carry up to 32GB DDR4 2400mhz SDRAM as specified in the [product page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-elitebook-840-g4-notebook-pc/11122291/document/c05349510#AbT5).

[image]

Comment: The 32GB limitation is due to the maximum module size supported by the motherboard.  It wasn't until the 8th and 9th Generation Core processors did mainboards support 32GB modules, of course even then, very few 32 GB modules even existed until recently.  Since the motherboard has only 2 DDR4 slots the only way to support 64 GB is with those 32 GB modules.

Comment: So are u saying I can have 32 GB RAM in 2 places for DDR4? kindly let me know @Ramhound

Comment: @Hashim - Your motherboard does not support 32 GB DDR4 modules.  I made this clear in my comment, in an attempt, to explain the reason your system only supports a maximum of 32 GB of memory.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 32GB maximum, and this is the limitation of the processor Intel Core i5-7200U
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/95443/intel-core-i57200u-processor-3m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz.html

Scroll down to Memory Specifications, it says:
Maximal Memory Size = 32 GB

(as was explained by @Ramhound in the comment above)

Comment: How is this better than the other answer that states the same?

Comment: @DarkDiamond: I did not understand the reason why there is the limitation presented in the table in the CaldeiraG's answer, and wanted to double check this info myself. Also, the comment of Ramhound's was very helpful and hinted for the real reason, but I wanted to double check this info as well and get some proof! That is why I found a technical information on the CPU itself, which states explicitly in no uncertain terms that this sort of CPU supports only 32GB of RAM. I was researching this for myself, as I got a similar computer recently and wanted to upgrade it as much as possible. Alas!